# I can not build my project after adding google admob dependencies

Tags: android, androidx

After adding google Admob dependencie a couldn't build my project.So i migrated to Androidx then i have bunch of errors.Especialy in my fragments.

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\DT User3\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b4ff399857e82d00548bc792e5cf526d\res\color\abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material.xml:20: error: attribute alpha (aka com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\DT User3\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b4ff399857e82d00548bc792e5cf526d\res\color\abc_btn_colored_text_material.xml:20: error: attribute alpha (aka com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\DT User3\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b4ff399857e82d00548bc792e5cf526d\res\color\abc_tint_btn_checkable.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\DT User3\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b4ff399857e82d00548bc792e5cf526d\res\color\abc_tint_default.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\DT User3\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b4ff399857e82d00548bc792e5cf526d\res\color\abc_tint_edittext.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\DT User3\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b4ff399857e82d00548bc792e5cf526d\res\color\abc_tint_seek_thumb.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\DT User3\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b4ff399857e82d00548bc792e5cf526d\res\color\abc_tint_spinner.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\DT User3\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b4ff399857e82d00548bc792e5cf526d\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:19: error: attribute alpha (aka com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\DT User3\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b4ff399857e82d00548bc792e5cf526d\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:20: error: attribute alpha (aka com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\DT User3\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b4ff399857e82d00548bc792e5cf526d\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:21: error: attribute alpha (aka com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow:alpha) not found.
C:\Users\DT User3\Desktop\StopSmokingNow\app\src\main\res\font\abril_fatface.xml:2: error: attribute fontProviderAuthority (aka com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow:fontProviderAuthority) not found.
C:\Users\DT User3\Desktop\StopSmokingNow\app\src\main\res\font\abril_fatface.xml:2: error: attribute fontProviderCerts (aka com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow:fontProviderCerts) not found.
C:\Users\DT User3\Desktop\StopSmokingNow\app\src\main\res\font\abril_fatface.xml:2: error: attribute fontProviderPackage (aka com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow:fontProviderPackage) not found.
C:\Users\DT User3\Desktop\StopSmokingNow\app\src\main\res\font\abril_fatface.xml:2: error: attribute fontProviderQuery (aka com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow:fontProviderQuery) not found.
C:\Users\DT User3\Desktop\StopSmokingNow\app\src\main\res\font\alex_brush.xml:2: error: attribute fontProviderAuthority (aka com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow:fontProviderAuthority) not found.
C:\Users\DT User3\Desktop\StopSmokingNow\app\src\main\res\font\alex_brush.xml:2: error: attribute fontProviderCerts (aka com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow:fontProviderCerts) not found.
```

And this is my Gradle file it looks all fine i think.And have problems within fragment with getActivity.getFragmentManager and @Nonnull is not recognized

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much time and no answer i did it.First i downloaded last gradle then updated dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.samex.android.stopsmokingnow"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.1@aar'
  implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
  //  implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
  //  implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'


   // implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'


    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

Then manualy downloaded gradle and posted as default for this project so i was able to compile and build.Thanks everyone for no ansering.Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :** Check if all dependency successfully converted into androidx ? if not do first.

**Solution 2 :** Upgrade your all gradle version to latest one. then do a Clean and Rebuild.

**Solution 3 :** Goto File -> Invalidate Caches & Restart.

If you still facing same problem kindly share your gradle file. So,We can observe that and give proper solution.

Comment: I did it all but it doesnt work,i just screwud up my almost 2 month project

Comment: And i added my gradle file and some more details so i hope you can help me